# Is there any relationship between Altcoin domain name and its validity?

Tags: altcoin, domain-registering

We are seeing many new alcoins coming to the market. However a lot of them have very weird websites. `io`, `org` etc.

But yesterdayi noticed a new altcoin GAME https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/game/  And one thing that captured my eye was the domain . It is game.com

It must be worth millions of dollars

I don't know if I should invest in it. So I wanted to ask experts if there is a correlation between the super expensive domain and validity of altcoin

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the short term exchange rate of the altcoin, but "validity" is not the same and highly opinion based. I'm voting to close this for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between the value of a domain name and the future value of an altcoin. You can only glean that *possibly* the altcoin creators had financial backing. Also, they could have used all of their finances on the domain name and have nothing left.

In theory, having the money to do so *can* result in a superior product, as superior engineers *could* be employed but, the product is the result of so many design decisions which must then be coded, it is not possible to say if it *will* be of any particular quality or another.

There is no direct relationship between the financials of the creators of an altcoin and the method of operation they choose for the altcoin, or the security, quality or, superiority of any product. Some very rich people make some very cheap products.

Answer (score 0):

There may be cases where there is a relationship between the owners of a domain and the maintainers/ developers of a cryptocurrency. But this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you. Actually their website looks basic. I don't know what they do. There is no source code. So i'm super hesitating. But i checked on estibot   . . game.com is crazy half a million.   There must be something solid behind it. But yet you are right there must be something going on between relationship between the owners of a domain and the maintainers/ developers of a cryptocurrency.